# Kubernetes mount volume with noatime

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Is there a way to mount a volume with the noatime flag in Kubernetes? I am using Google container engine. The volumes are for the data directories of a Riak database and it is more performant with noatime.

Comment: Did you solve this? 1.6 introduced [https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#mount-options](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#mount-options) which might be solving this.